# Linearity of a map demonstrates that the tensor must have one vector space

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors, general-relativity, dual-spaces

> Thus, we have shown that $\bar{\bigtriangledown}_a- \bigtriangledown_a$ defines a map of dual vectors at p to tensors of type $(0,2)$ at $p$.
>
> By property (1), this map is linear. Consequently $(\bar{\bigtriangledown}_a- \bigtriangledown_a)$ defines a tensor of type $(1,2)$ at $p$.

How does this map being linear mean that $(\bar{\bigtriangledown}_a- \bigtriangledown_a)$ has a 1 and not 0 vector spaces? I cannot see how this is deduced.

This is from Wald's General Relativity, page 33.

Comment: Because it takes vectors to (0,2) tensors (and it is linear), so it is a (1,2) tensor.

Comment: Sorry but I still can't see that

Comment: You wrote it as $\bar{\nabla}_a \omega_b-\nabla_a\omega_b=C^c_{ab}\omega_c$. What type of tensor is $C^c_{ab}$?

Comment: @MBN could you put that as an answer please?